# VBA - StrComp type mismatch or subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am running a For Loop to find a string inside a variant array. I am using StrComp to compare the strings. The array that I am using as the following format.
[image]

I have tried two approaches which I will describe bellow.

**1st approach returns that the subscript is out of range when I use col=0**

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant, col As Integer) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsInArray = -1

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i, col), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      IsInArray = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function
```

**2nd approach tells me type mismatch at the StrComp**

```
Function IsIn1DArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsIn1DArray = -1

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i)) = 0 Then
      IsIn1DArray = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function
```

I have been using the IsInArray and IsIn1DArray in the past and works but not for this case. Imagine I would like to search for the string "[TestHeader]" and return its index. How would you do it?

Comment: does not work. the string does not come from a cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is an array of arrays, so you need:

```
If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i)(col), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

Note this may fail for some values as your sub arrays are not the same size, so you should test the `Ubound` of the subarray first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsIn1dArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long

    IsIn1dArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0)

End Function
```